# PHP,Codeigniter, where can I find in which file the information I view on the web is written?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter. I'm working on a ready-made project, I need to change a few information, but it cannot be accessed by right-clicking and inspect, as usual. Is there a shortcut that I can access directly instead of looking at all the files one by one? [For example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsaMq.png)
I want to change 'total tax' to amount i found table page that i can change title but i dont know where can i change the table data.

Comment: Maybe hire someone that knows what they are doing in this case.

Comment: That is within a Datatable so it maybe in the JS. However in this instance probably best to do a search across all files for the particular words and that will help you find it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.